# getting error undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

getting this error
"undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass",  when working with paperclip in ruby. please tell me the appropriate answer 4 this...

Comment: You'll get that method any time a method called `exitstatus` is called on `nil`, usually when you think you have an object but you really don't. To help you, we are going to need more details, for example, a stack trace and perhaps some of the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

Check your /config/enviroments/production.rb(or development) file and set convert command path for ImageMagick.

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when I tried to assign attachment this way:

```
file = new Tempfile("image.png")    
user.image = file
```

It worked after I changed it to this:

```
user.image = File.open("image.png")
```

If this wasn't your case, you should give a little more information about your problem.